# Reporting Tool For Asp.Net MVC 3 Razor View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, reporting-services, reporting

Can You suggest any Good **Reporting Tool** for create reports with **Asp.net MVC 3 razor view ?**

**It should provide features like**

Master-Details reports

Table reports

Report merging

Side-by-Side reports

Pivot Grid

charts and Graph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PdfReport is able to produce the above reports for both web and windows applications: http://pdfreport.codeplex.com/. Here you can find its samples: http://pdfreport.codeplex.com/SourceControl/BrowseLatest